# Import HeroDetailComponent from official Angular 2 Tutorial

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm going trough Angular 2 "Tour of Heroes" tutorial.

Angular 2 is new technology for me. I stuck on step 5 on "Services"
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

I followed tutorial at all but for some reasons importing `hero-detail.component.ts` doesn't work for me.

I copied everything at the end from this Plunker https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-4/ts/plnkr.html
but I'm getting following errors when I try to start server with `npm start`

```
$ npm start

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start E:\Potta\Angular 2\my-first-angular-2
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"

app/app.component.ts(4,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module './hero-detail.component'.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\Potta\Angular 2\my-first-angular-2\npm-debug.log
```

Here is **app.components.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>My Heroes</h2>
    <ul class="heroes">
      <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
        [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
        (click)="onSelect(hero)">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .selected {
      background-color: #CFD8DC !important;
      color: white;
    }
    .heroes {
      margin: 0 0 2em 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      width: 15em;
    }
    .heroes li {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #EEE;
      margin: .5em;
      padding: .3em 0;
      height: 1.6em;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .heroes li.selected:hover {
      background-color: #BBD8DC !important;
      color: white;
    }
    .heroes li:hover {
      color: #607D8B;
      background-color: #DDD;
      left: .1em;
    }
    .heroes .text {
      position: relative;
      top: -3px;
    }
    .heroes .badge {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: small;
      color: white;
      padding: 0.8em 0.7em 0 0.7em;
      background-color: #607D8B;
      line-height: 1em;
      position: relative;
      left: -1px;
      top: -4px;
      height: 1.8em;
      margin-right: .8em;
      border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    }
  `],
  directives: [HeroDetailComponent],
  providers: [HeroService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  getHeroes() {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

And here is **hero-detail.component.ts**

```js
  import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { Hero } from './hero';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-hero-detail',
      template: `
        <div *ngIf="hero">
          <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
          <div>
            <label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>name: </label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      `
    })
    export class HeroDetailComponent {
      @Input() hero: Hero;
    }
```

On the next image you can see structure and also that WebStorm tells me how he is not able to find component, but I really don't know why.

http://prntscr.com/bml0nx

Any kind of help will be appreaciated.

Also, here is **systemjs.config.js** in a case that you need it:

```js
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 apps
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',

    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];

  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  };

  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

**RESOLVED**

There was typo for the name `hero-detail.component**s**.ts`

There was 's' at the end instead to be `hero-detail.component.ts`.

Comment: Your plunker is empty

Comment: @AngJobs you are right. Check now, now it is not. Thank you

Comment: before running `start` and `tsc` try to `cd` into `\Angular 2\my-first-angular-2`

Comment: @AngJobs I did: http://prntscr.com/bmlb0z

Comment: @AngJobs any ideas what can be problem ?

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` in your folder?

Comment: I get an error when I run `npm start` I think the problem is not with the code but with running a web server. Because this is working if I put it on my local IIS

Comment: your hero detail component file is named "hero-detail.component**s**.ts" with the s, but you are trying to import from hero-detail.component - no s, add the s and webstorm will stop throwing a fit

Comment: @JarodMoser Excellent ! I renamed hero-detail.components to .component and it works. What a stupid issue that was very hard for me to see. Thank you.

Now it compiles and it works. WebStorm showing syntax errors and I don't know why because code works and everything is compiled properly. 
http://prntscr.com/bmm6jj